# How get related objects by field name?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have these models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
        name =   models.CharField(blank=True)

class Element(models.Model):
    name =   models.CharField(blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='places', blank=False, null=True)
```

How to get all categories by name of field?

`element._meta.get_field('category')` return ManyToManyField. How to get all categories from this object

UPD: I need an access by name: I iterated by field names and collect related objects.

Example:

```
names = []
for field_name in ['categories', 'some_another_m2m_field_name']:
    for related_object in objects._meta.get_field(field_name).all():
        names.append(related_object.name)
```

thank you

Comment: `element.categories.all()`?

Comment: No. I need an access by name: I iterated by field names and collect related objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do I guess:

```
element._meta.get_field('categories').value_from_object(element)
```